# Xamarin iOS nav bar title missing in iOS16.0 when app built with Xcode 14.0

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, navbar, page-title

This issue is for Xamarin iOS apps built in Xcode 14.0 and running in iOS16.0.

Where a page title is set other than in the page constructor (for example in OnAppearing), the page title is not shown - missing - when first displayed. If you push out of the page and later return to it, now the title will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be caused by an Apple bug in iOS 16.0 / Xcode 14.0. Two ways to work around it:

1. Move your title-setting code to the page constructor.
2. Leave the title-setting code where it is and add the following to the page constructor:

```
Title = "\uFEFF";  // Non-printing non-blank Unicode character
```

Apparently, if the Title is null, empty or blank in the constructor, the alpha of the text is set to 0.

No doubt Apple will fix this in later versions, but the problem remains for the current versions I believe.

Comment: If you find the root cause, you can mark it as an answer as it's helpful to others facing the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT My answer is correct, it fixed my app in about 35 pages in fact. Stack Overflow has not yet allowed me to mark it as a solution, as not enough time has elapsed.